# Hiccup on looping lego walk cycle

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, keyframes

I have noticed that’s this topic seems to be a common theme but what ever I have seen on other questions doesn’t seem to help. My character starts in the middle with his walk cycle and using math walks perfectly, and when he restarts the cycle I just move the master bone so it mirrored the spot he was last in. He doesn’t jump or anything the issue is when viewing it on a really low frame rate you can see a slight pause. The key frames for him stopping and starting again have the same look so is the issue that the key frames need to be changed? If so how, I can’t figure out how to change them and still have the animation play!
Thanks for your help!

I had to re animate the character so his upper body is not animated!

EDIT : Here is my Blend [image]

[image: FrameBefore]

[image: FrameAfter]

EDIT 2: Between these two images the character is in almost the same spot and so I think this causes the issue, I just don't know how to solve it!
I have to reset the master bone so the animation can be a cycle and not me animating over and over again. This image below shows the keyframes and the ones that double up every time is where it resets!

Thanks so much for your help again!

[image: The Keyframes are right next to each other but you can barely see the pause.]

Comment: hello, please share the armature with its animation: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Done! The Link is Up above!

Comment: are you sure you've shared the right file? I can't see any character nor any armature, please simplify as much as possible, only share the armature, or armature + character if necessary

Comment: Ack the issue might be that I have the zmbx mecabricks blender addon so I don’t m or if that changed anything, and I use epic fig rig for the armature.

Comment: I edited the post again to show more info and make my problem clearer.

Comment: could you please share the file with only the object and armature (or at least the armature), I couldn't find them in the original file

Comment: Sorry thats what I did already but I will try it myself

Comment: I downloaded the blend and everything showed up and was there! I don't understand what's wrong sorry.

Comment: maybe it's a linked object (not sure)?

Comment: I use this for the armature, https://github.com/BlenderBricks/EpicFigRig

Comment: And this for the shader for the legos so they show up, https://www.mecabricks.com/en/shop/product/2

Comment: I don't know why I can't see your object, I hope someone will understand

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned (Edit 2) the hiccup is caused by 2 (or more) frames that are very similar when you move the master bone. A solution might be to shorten the walk cycle by one frame as described here: [How to create a seamless animation loop in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141712/107598)

In addition, the motion of the body does not appear to be constant over time. In some frames, when the legs are apart, the body has a fast forward motion. While it barely moves forward when the other leg passes the standing leg. This creates that "striding like at a wedding" effect. Maybe you can fix it by re-arranging the keyframes/poses.

[image: walk cycle animation]

I am not an expert on animation but I think you can create an action for the walk cycle and repeat this action in the NLA editor. So you don't have to animate it over and over again. Have a look here:  [How should an animated character be moved while repeating a walk cycle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3736/107598)

Comment: The issue is that the frame before I move the master bone needs to be that way so that the legs don’t get all messed up and get ruined, when the frame rate increases it becomes harder to notice. The frame after is the positions reset.

Comment: I fixed my problem, i redid the entire animation and when I did the frame before needs to have the leg a little farther back I believe.